# Having trouble using Spring with Java

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use Spring with Intellij but I'm having major issues getting started.  Here's what I've tried, and what's happened:

I used this documentation about getting started and enabling spring support: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-spring-support.html

It tells me to go to plugins and enable Spring Support, but spring support does not show up in the list of available downloads.

I uninstalled Intellij and started over from scratch.  When I installed, I made sure to check the Spring plugins option, but that didn't actually do anything and Spring was not installed.

I tried several times again to troubleshoot the issue, and only ran into documentation that was kind of complex for my level of skill.  I'm really frustrated at this point: any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have Intellij Idea Ultimate Edition? Supported only in Ultimate Edition: Spring Framework — Core, MVC, WebFlow, Web Service, Data, Security, Integration, Roo, etc.

Comment: Only Ultimate Edition supports it? That makes so much sense! Now I feel really dumb